# Show unity launcher on with key combination

Tags: unity, launcher, shortcuts, autohide

I wanted to ask if it is possible to pub unity launcher on autohide and have 2 ways of showing it. First is obvious with mouse, and second with some type of key combination, like ctrl+shift.

Edit: It would be nice I launcher would be shown for only as long as ctrl+shift is pressed. As soon as I remove my fingers launcher should hide.

Comment: You can always just hold <super>.

Comment: Moreover, if you hold <super> for more than 2 seconds, you'll get a list of very many key combinations to do all kinds of things.

Comment: @Seth model M keyboards do not have a <super> key

Answer (score 10):

1. You can use the "Super" button for this. Most keyboards and notebooks have a button with a "Windows" logo on it.

As long as you press the button, the launcher is visible.

1. An other solution, if you press Alt+F1, after that the Launcher appears, press again Alt+F1, the Launcher disappears.

Comment: is there a way I can re-assign the alt-f1 functionality to another key combo? Atm I have set the panel to whow with another key combo through compiz, but this results in the dash launcher window being open automatically which is extremely annoying.